# How to connect in a php file with phonegap in apple?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile, cordova

I would like to connect a phonegap apple application with a php file. I have used this javascript function to do this

```
$.post(myphpfileUrl, { login: loginName, password:loginPassword },
           function(data) {
        //  alert(data);        
        }else{
            alert("connexion problems");

        }

           });
```

And this is my phpfile

```
<?php exit("youppieee");?>
```

But I didn't have answer with my iPhone. I have answer just with my android.

Comment: This is way too less code to give you some advise.

Comment: What's the value of `myphpfileUrl`? Also, what answer did you get on Android? I'm curious...

Comment: myphpfilurl are the url to my php file. Exemple : http://123.45.678.91/AfolderName/filename.php (they are fictive name). ypieeee are just a test. According to the numbers returned I know the login is correct

Comment: Dainis Abols:  What other information do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I have resolve my problems. I was call a ip adresse of my server (123.45.67.89/myfolder/myphpFile) but the problems was resolved in the moment of I calling the server domaineName(ex:mydomaineName/myfolder/myphpFile)

Answer (score 0):

Your php code is wrong:

```
<?php echo "youppieee";?>
```

Comment: I have tested with echo. But this didn't change the problems. exit is best for my needs. I send just one information.This is a little exemple.But this little exemple don't works.